# Screwy USB - is this even fixable

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive

I attempted to create a bootable USB drive with Kali Linux or Tails (not sure which). An error occurred during the process of flashing the drive, and I saw an icon saying the USB had malfunctioned. After removing and re-inserting the drive, I saw this lovely issue:

[image]

If someone could help me figure out how to resolve this issue (obviously drive D), it would be much appreciated.
PS: I need a fix asap, and I have tried to format the drive.

Comment: What do you see for the drive in Drive Management?

Comment: @DragonLord Disk management reports a 125 MB drive, originally this was a 0.9 GiG.

Comment: Sounds like you messed up the partition table, try writing the image to the drive again.

Comment: I would, but the drive is now reporting itself being ridiculously small and therefore Rufus fails to write the image as the drive appears too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did you check the intergy of the image of the operating system?**

If not, it's entirely possible that there was an issue with the operating system's image, causing the program you were using to write the image to prematurely 'complete' the write; this would cause Windows to detect a hardware 'malfunction' (as it's trying to read a file that the partition table on the drive says exists, but actually doesn't) *and* would corrupt the partition table causing Windows to recognise it as a ***RAW*** partition (aka, unformatted).

You need to double click the drive and format it in `Computer`, `This PC`, or `My Computer` (depending on which version of Windows you're running) when it tells you the drive needs to be formatted before you use it.

If that doesn't work, you can try formatting it in Disk Manager or Windows' commandline partition management tool, Diskpart.

**Diskpart:**

1. Open a command prompt by using the key combination <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `diskpart` to launch the Diskpart tool- click 'Yes' when the UAC prompt comes up
3. Type `list disk`, find and note the drive number of your USB stick
4. Now type `select disk #`, where '#' is the drive number of your USB stick that you noted in the previous step
5. Type `clean`- **this will completely format the selected drive**
6. Go back to `My Computer`, `This PC`, or `Computer`, and try formatting the drive again, it should now work.

If this doesn't work, the USB drive is broken and you will need to get a new one. I'd suggest using a tool such as [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) to download and put the desired installation image onto the new USB stick.
***Do NOT use the same operating system installation image that you used before (if you must use it, redownload it!)***

Comment: Well then. Yes, windows is seeing the drive as a raw parturition. However, I cannot format the drive to fix this issue. Could you explain how this could be fixed if at all?

Comment: @magi093 Getting to that now, was distracted when typing the answer up.

Comment: And no, like the idiot I am I didn't check the image. Will do in the future.

Comment: @magi093 That's why the majority of OS download pages provide the MD5 signature for the file their end. Complete answer is there now.

Comment: smeg with curry on top. the drive is busted. great... thanks for the help anyway.